# Implementing Specific action per Active View in Caliburn Micro

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a WPF app I'm writing using the Caliburn.Micro MVVM framework.

My `ShellViewModel` is a conductor and thus has `ActiveItem` and I'm able to switch between `ActiveItem`s fine.

My problem comes to handling my application menu. It's in the `ShellView.xaml` markup and I have a "Save" menu item. I want this to pass off to the `ActiveItem`s `Save()` method, and also bind to the `CanSave` guard property on the ActiveItem as well disabled when there is not an Active item or the Active Item doesn't support saving.

I can't see an easy way of handling case. Has any one else tried something similar, did they find a good way to do this with Caliburn.Micro?

I have other idea's on how to do this, but with everything else Caliburn.Micro offers, I feel I must be missing something simple.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Event Aggregator to publish a Save event and have the active item, `IsActive`, handle the SaveEvent.

For the guard you could have the CanSave test a value that is shared between the ShellVM and an ActiveItem using MEF.